# Creating shortcut that will use dynamic %username%

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to create a shortcut on users' desktops that will point to a share where they will back up their .pst files. I've borrowed code that creates the shortcut using the `%username%` variable, and it works if I run it logged in as myself. When the actual user logs in, however, it still has my name as the user instead of the currently logged in user. How do I make it variable?

Here is the code:

```
# Create a Shortcut with Windows PowerShell
$TargetFile = "\\fileserver\%username%$"
$ShortcutFile = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Mail.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

The code works and creates a shortcut on the desktop when I log in. But when another user logs in, instead of using their username as `%username%`, my username gets populated since I ran the script. Is there a way to make that dynamic so that whoever logs in will have a shortcut to their share on the network?

Comment: I guess the Shell object already performs environment variable expansion on the target path here. Did you take a look at the properties of the created shortcut?

Comment: What OS Version are you using? In practice I cannot get this to work but apparently you used to be able to on 03 and XP. Can't find a reputable source yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cheat with Windows Explorer**

Credit goes to the gentleman on this [TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/16b71d26-7828-46ea-881a-66198cc88ab8/solved-dynamic-shortcuts-with-environment-variables?forum=w7itproui). Environment Path variable expansion works fine for prefixing path just easy but does not seem to allow midpath expansion. I don't know if that generalization is correct but in practice it was true.

```
$TargetFile = "%windir%\explorer.exe" 
$arguments = '/e,"\\fileserver\%username%$"'
$ShortcutFile = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Mail.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Arguments = $arguments
$Shortcut.Save()
```

So we call windows explorer with the [/e argument](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/130510) and then specifying the target path with the environment variable pre expansion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut->

```
explorer.exe "\\fileserver\%username%$"
```

or place a shortcut with VBscript